# How to create a pd.Series from a frequency table?

Tags: python, pandas

I have my (integer) values and their counts. How can I create a Series based on that?

An example dataset would be `{0:21,1:13,2:5,3:4,4:2,5:3,6:2}`, I want this to be the output of `value_counts()` of the Series I make.

I tried `np.repeat`s in `concatenate` but I'm getting an error as it apparently can't be vectorized.

**Edit:** So here is an example to clarify things. As the dictionary above shows, I have twenty-one 0s, thirteen 1s, five 2s and so on. I would like my Series look like something like this: `0 0 ... 0 1 1 ... 1 2 2 2 2 2` without having to manually enter the same data multiple times.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your current data and what is your expected output?

Comment: @IoaTzimas I added a bit more explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @zareami10 let me know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pandas Series [repeat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) method:

```
values = pd.Series(counts.keys()).repeat(list(counts.values()))

values.value_counts()

0    21
1    13
2     5
3     4
5     3
6     2
4     2
dtype: int64
```

If you want something faster than the accepted solution, then you could use numpy [repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat):

```
values = pd.Series(np.repeat(list(counts.keys()), list(counts.values())))
values.value_counts()

0    21
1    13
2     5
3     4
5     3
6     2
4     2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
counts = {0:21,1:13,2:5,3:4,4:2,5:3,6:2}

# here we create it
values = pd.Series(np.hstack([[v]*c for v,c in counts.items()]))

# check
values.value_counts()
```

output

```
0    21
1    13
2     5
3     4
5     3
6     2
4     2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @zareami10 glad you like it. enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

***Simplest solution***

```
empty_list = []
for key,value in dict.items():
    for i in range(value):
        empty_list.append(key)
series = pd.Series(np.array(empty_list))
series.value_counts()        
#output
0    21
1    13
2     5
3     4
5     3
6     2
4     2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data = {0:21,1:13,2:5,3:4,4:2,5:3,6:2}
s = pd.Series(data)
```

gives

```
0    21
1    13
2     5
3     4
4     2
5     3
6     2
dtype: int64
```

is this what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use itertools for this.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    frequencies = {0: 21, 1: 13, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 2}
    series = pd.Series(data=chain.from_iterable((repeat(x, count)) for x, count in frequencies.items()))
    print(series)
```